# Open Zariski subsets of $\mathbb{P}^1$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, projective-space, zariski-topology

Are open subsets of $\mathbb{P^1}$ connected? I believe yes because they are complement of finite sets. Is this right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The projective line is irreducible. An open subset of an irreducible space is irreducible, which is a much stronger property than connectedness.

Comment: That was indeed what I realized like ten minutes after I posted it. Thank you for the precise answer anyway!

Comment: @GiovanniBruno: I'm happy you like it. You should also accept it, though (otherwise, it is going to stay on the list of unanswered questions).

Comment: @GiovanniBruno: By the way, you may not know that in such case, it is perfectly fine to answer your own question (and accept the answer, if there is no better one).